# Swift / how to get core data entries by valueForKey

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code to return multiple dates as NSDate

```
    func setUpDays() {

        var datesArray = [String]()
        datesArray.append("28.03.2016")
        datesArray.append("26.03.2016")
        datesArray.append("27.03.2016")    

        for i in 0...datesArray.count-1 {

            let dates2Convert = datesArray[i]

            let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
            let day = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dates2Convert)

            print(day)
        }
    }
```

That is working perfectly. Now I want to get those dates from core data instead of the datesArray

```
var dates = [NSManagedObject]()

    func setUpDays() {

        for i in 0...2 {

            let currentDates = dates[i]
            let date2Convert = currentDates.valueForKey("date") as? String

            let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
            let day = dateFormatter.dateFromString(date2Convert)

            print(day)
        }
    }
```

But `let currentDates = dates[i]` code is throwing the following exception:

[image]

The dates are correctly saves in the core data. If I'll print em out, they're correct. What am I missing? Help is very appreciated.

As requested: This is how core data is filled with a date string.

```
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {

let str = string.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())

if parsedElement == "eventDates" && str != "" {
    if currentEvent.eventDates.isEmpty {

        currentEvent.eventDates = str
        parsedElement = ""

        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
        let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Calendar", inManagedObjectContext:managedContext)
        let datum = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
        datum.setValue(currentEvent.eventDates, forKey: "date")

        do {
            try managedContext.save()
            //5

            dates.append(datum)
        } catch let error as NSError  {
            print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Well...`dates` seems nil or empty I guess :-) Can you show where/how you declare the `dates` array?

Comment: what is `currentDates` ?  sound like an array, because you have named it in plural.  If it's meant to be a single instance, it should be `currentDate`  When you inspect `dates[]` is it an array of String, or an array of CoreData objects?

Comment: `dates = [NSManagedObject]()`

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: @pbodsk dates should not nil. I use dates.count as return of how many table rows are visible and the count is correct. as least If I don't use this function. If I use it, the app crashes, before the view is loaded.

Comment: How many objects are there in `dates` when you start your loop?  (`for i in 0...2` assumes three.)

Comment: @Russell yes I guess it shoult be singular, since in that for loop, it's an single element

Comment: @PhillipMills 3 string elements are saved inside the core data (dates)

Comment: But are there three in the array when the loop is entered?

Comment: @PhillipMills actually there are 4 date string in the core data

Comment: but 0...3 crashes, too

Comment: OK, the problem then is - as @PhillipMills says - that you try to reference an element in your `dates` array that isn't there (at least not when you try to fetch it). What happens if you place a breakpoint at the `let currentDates = dates[i]` line and then inspect what the value of `dates` is...I'm guessing it is empty

Comment: well I can't see the elements of `dates`, there is simply nothing shown for `dates`at the breakpoint inspector. But if I print(dates.count), it's empty... so I guess you're right. so.. what's my option?

Comment: ps. console says: `fatal error: Array index out of range`

Comment: ugh...I was hoping you didn't ask me that ;-) OK, I guess it'd be interesting to see how you load the `dates` array. In the above code you just create an empty dates array `var dates = [NSManagedObject]()`, but do you try to populate it somewhere? (apart from `parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String)` which I'm guessing isn't called before you call `setupDates()`)

Comment: @pbodsk I'm just populating the `dates` array at the parser function which is located at literally the last function in the whole viewcontroller code as an extension.

Comment: OK, and when do you call `setupDates()`? Before you parse XML I guess, since the `dates` array is empty.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106608/discussion-between-pbodsk-and-david-seek).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As can be seen in the lengthy chat, the problem was that `dates` was initialized and attempted accessed in `viewDidLoad()`. However, it wasn't populated yet, as that happened in the XML parse method.

To make it more crash safe this loop

```
for i in 0...2 {
   let currentDates = dates[i]
   let date2Convert = currentDates.valueForKey("date") as? String

   let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
   dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
   let day = dateFormatter.dateFromString(date2Convert)

   print(day)
}
```

was replaced with this loop

```
dates.forEach { currentDate in
   let date2Convert = currentDate.valueForKey("date") as? String

   let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
   dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy"
   let day = dateFormatter.dateFromString(date2Convert)

   print(day)
}
```

And then the `setupDates()` method was called after parsing was ended.

Comment: thank you again for your amazing help and high effort!

Comment: You're welcome, just glad to be able to help someone when they're stuck